# "Trying to read" "bytes at“ "outside the bounds of the file"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, recovery

I have a slight issue.

Yesterday we had a power outage while we were importing data into the MySQL server inside a Docker container.

I'm trying to perform data recovery because this is what the log files says:

> 2023-01-20 23:09:04 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to read 16384 bytes at 70368744161280 outside the bounds of the file: ./ibdata1
>
> 2023-01-20 23:09:04 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to read 16384 bytes at 70368744161280 outside the bounds of the file: ./ibdata1
>
> 2023-01-20 23:09:04 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to read 16384 bytes at 70368744161280 outside the bounds of the file: ./ibdata1
>
> 2023-01-20 23:09:04 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=370571] log sequence number 685813904476 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 432631856.
>
> 2023-01-20 23:09:04 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
>
> 2023-01-20 23:09:04 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to read 16384 bytes at 70368744161280 outside the bounds of the file: ./ibdata1

The `ib_lofile0` might be corrput, is there a way to rebuild the `ib_lofile0` or ignore it to do a database dump? Or otherwise force it into the recovery mode?

Comment: Did you move any files around?

Comment: There are some InnoDB recovery methods discussed in this forum and in the manual.